# How to mount encfs in a LXC container

Tags: container, encfs

When trying to mount, I have the following error:

```
container# encfs /toto /mnt
EncFS Password: 
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
fuse failed.  Common problems:
 - fuse kernel module not installed (modprobe fuse)
 - invalid options -- see usage message
```

When I try modprobe:

```
container# modprobe fuse
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-86-generic/modules.dep.bin'
```

Is something missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:
    mknod -m 666 /dev/fuse c 10 229

666 = perms
c = character device
10 = minor num for /dev/fuse in the host
229 = major num for /dev/fuse in the host

Thanks to 
https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/kernel-module-fuse-for-lxc.24855/